# How to bind an endpoint to adminConnector in dropwizard?

Tags: dropwizard

In a dropwizard project, the configuration yaml file typically defines two sub-components for server configuration - applicationConnectors and adminConnectors. For example, the app connector may use http port 8080 and the admin connector may use port 8081.

By default, the admin port exposes "Operational Menu" and has subitems such as Metrics, Healthcheck, etc.

I am wondering how I can programmatically set an endpoint "/myhelloworld" to use the admin port. Guessing this has to be done in the "initialize" method of the main application.